# Conditional file reading in python

Tags: python, list, file, csv

Suppose there are a collection of CSV files, i.e. A.csv, B.csv, C.csv………Z.csv

```
'A.csv'
'B.csv'
'C.csv'
'D.csv'
....
'X.csv'
'Y.csv'
'Z.csv'
```

If a list of vowels and consonants are created i.e. A.csv, E.csv, I.csv,O.csv,U.csv are listed in a list as vowels as follows:

```
VOWELS = ['A.csv','E.csv','I.csv','O.csv','U.csv']
```

and files are read as:

```
file_path = r"C:\Users\Desktop\Data"
read_files = glob.glob(file_path,"*.csv")
```

while others are listed in a list called as consonants, How can we import the files listed in the vowel list from the main directory? I am using the following code but there is no output and not even error. What could have been wrong?

```
for i in range(len(VOWELS)):
        #print (VOWELS[i])
    for file in read_files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, VOWELS[i]):
            print(file)
```

Comment: For debugging, print out `file` and `VOWELS[i]` before the conditional so that you can directly compare the differences. The reason nothing is being printed is because that conditional block is never entered, meaning those values do not match.

Comment: Thanks. When printing, I see the output from `VOWELS[i]` but the next for loop seems to be the problem. Nothing is printed out as I print the `file`. What could be the reason?

Comment: Yes - if `file` is `None`, your called to `glob.glob` is not functioning properly, so trace your steps back to there and see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would work. The ending of the file will be in your vowel list.

```
import glob

file_path = r"C://test//"
read_files = glob.glob(file_path + "*.csv")

VOWELS = ['A.csv','E.csv','I.csv','O.csv','U.csv']

for file in read_files:
    for vowel in VOWELS:
        if file.endswith(vowel):
             print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
import glob

VOWELS = ["A.csv", "E.csv", "I.csv", "O.csv", "U.csv"]


file_path = r"C:\Users\Desktop\Data\%s"


for lookup_file in glob.glob(file_path % "*.csv"):
    if lookup_file.rsplit("\\", 1)[1] in VOWELS:
        print(i)
```